# Is there a foreach in MATLAB? If so, how does it behave if the underlying data changes?

Tags: matlab, syntax

Is there a foreach structure in MATLAB?  If so, what happens if the underlying data changes (i.e. if objects are added to the set)?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

MATLAB's **FOR** loop is static in nature; you cannot modify the loop variable between iterations, unlike the **for(initialization;condition;increment)** loop structure in other languages. This means that the following code always prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 regardless of the value of B.

```
A = 1:5;

for i = A
    A = B;
    disp(i);
end
```

If you want to be able to respond to changes in the data structure during iterations, a [**WHILE** loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html?s_tid=doc_ta) may be more appropriate --- you'll be able to test the loop condition at every iteration, and set the value of the loop variable(s) as you wish:

```
n = 10;
f = n;
while n > 1
    n = n-1;
    f = f*n;
end
disp(['n! = ' num2str(f)])
```

Btw, the **for-each** loop [in Java](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (and possibly other languages) produces unspecified behavior when the data structure is modified during iteration. If you need to modify the data structure, you should use an appropriate **[Iterator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)** instance which allows the addition and removal of elements in the collection you are iterating. The good news is that MATLAB supports Java objects, so you can do something like this:

```
A = java.util.ArrayList();
A.add(1);
A.add(2);
A.add(3);
A.add(4);
A.add(5);

itr = A.listIterator();

while itr.hasNext()

    k = itr.next();
    disp(k);

    % modify data structure while iterating
    itr.remove();
    itr.add(k);

end
```

Comment: If B is undefined, your first example doesn't print 1-5. It prints `Undefined function or variable 'B'`.

Comment: For the 1st example make sure that `A` is a row vector, not column vector. If `A` is a matrix, each k will be a column vector from that matrix. So, transpose(`A'`) or vectorize (`A(:)'`) if needed.

Comment: -1 I do _not_ think Java-like code should be your first choice way to work with Matlab in `.m` files.

Comment: greetings from the future; we come with plenty of solutions to iterator invalidation problem.

Answer (score 96):

Zach is correct about the direct answer to the question.

An interesting side note is that the following two loops do not execute the same:

```
for i=1:10000
  % do something
end
for i=[1:10000]
  % do something
end
```

The first loop creates a variable `i` that is a scalar and it iterates it like a C for loop.  Note that if you modify `i` in the loop body, the modified value will be ignored, as Zach says.  In the second case, Matlab creates a 10k-element array, then it walks all elements of the array.

What this means is that

```
for i=1:inf
  % do something
end
```

works, but

```
for i=[1:inf]
  % do something
end
```

does not (because this one would require allocating infinite memory).  See [Loren's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/07/19/how-for-works/) for details.

Also note that you can iterate over cell arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised about this when I ran into it.  This optimization of arrays actually takes place in many places.  If you use bracket notation, sometimes you'll see performance warnings in the Matlab editor telling you it thinks it can optimize out the array allocation if you let it.

Comment: I hear Matlab has lazy evaluation now. If not, we do have the technology to implement them.

Answer (score 21):

The MATLAB [for](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop basically allows huge flexibility, including the [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach) functionality. Here some examples:

1) Define start, increment and end index

```
for test = 1:3:9
   test
end
```

2) Loop over vector

```
for test = [1, 3, 4]
   test
end
```

3) Loop over string

```
for test = 'hello'
   test
end
```

4) Loop over a one-dimensional cell array

```
for test = {'hello', 42, datestr(now) ,1:3}
   test
end
```

5) Loop over a two-dimensional cell array

```
for test = {'hello',42,datestr(now) ; 'world',43,datestr(now+1)}
   test(1)   
   test(2)
   disp('---')
end
```

6) Use fieldnames of structure arrays

```
s.a = 1:3 ; s.b = 10  ; 
for test = fieldnames(s)'
   s.(cell2mat(test))
end
```

Comment: With the cell array, take note that it will iterate **over columns** of the cell array.

Answer (score 19):

If you are trying to loop over a cell array and apply something to each element in the cell, check out `cellfun`.  There's also `arrayfun`, `bsxfun`, and `structfun` which may simplify your program.

Comment: though, from experience I would say that their performance is equal or worst to writing a for-loop, better looking though, and who knows they might improve in the future.

Answer (score 15):

ooh! neat question.

Matlab's for loop takes a matrix as input and iterates over its columns. Matlab also handles practically everything by value (no pass-by-reference) so I would expect that it takes a snapshot of the for-loop's input so it's immutable.

here's an example which may help illustrate:

```
>> A = zeros(4); A(:) = 1:16

A =

     1     5     9    13
     2     6    10    14
     3     7    11    15
     4     8    12    16

>> i = 1; for col = A; disp(col'); A(:,i) = i; i = i + 1; end;
     1     2     3     4

     5     6     7     8

     9    10    11    12

    13    14    15    16

>> A

A =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 7):

When iterating over cell arrays of strings, the loop variable (let's call it `f`) becomes a single-element cell array. Having to write `f{1}` everywhere gets tedious, and modifying the loop variable provides a clean workaround.

```
% This example transposes each field of a struct.
s.a = 1:3;
s.b = zeros(2,3);
s % a: [1 2 3]; b: [2x3 double]
for f = fieldnames(s)'
    s.(f{1}) = s.(f{1})';
end
s % a: [3x1 double]; b: [3x2 double]

% Redefining f simplifies the indexing.
for f = fieldnames(s)'
    f = f{1};
    s.(f) = s.(f)';
end
s % back to a: [1 2 3]; b: [2x3 double]
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have an array of data:

```
n = [1    2   3   4   6   12  18  51  69  81  ]
```

then you can 'foreach' it like this:

```
for i = n, i, end
```

This will echo every element in n (but replacing the i with more interesting stuff is also possible of course!)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what the OP really wants:

```
array = -1:0.1:10

for i=1:numel(array)
    disp(array(i))
end
```

Comment: That just prints 10 since `numel(array)` is the number of elements in array. perhaps you meant `1:numel(array)`?

Comment: Wouldn't `for i = -1:0.1:10;   disp(i);   end;` be better ?

Answer (score 4):

As of today (Feb 27), [there is a new For-Each toolbox on the MATLAB File Exchange](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2015/02/27/for-each/) that accomplishes the concept of `foreach`. `foreach` is not a part of the MATLAB language but use of this toolbox gives us the ability to emulate what `foreach` would do.