# foreach loop with strings in Matlab

Tags: matlab, foreach

I want to create a loop that will iterate over several strings, but unable to do so in Matlab.

What works is:

```
for i=1:3
  if (i==1)
    b='cow';
  elseif (i==2)
    b='dog';
  else
    b='cat';
  end

  disp(b);
end
```

and the result is:

```
cow
dog
cat
```

But what I want is something more elegant that will look like:

```
for i=['cow','dog','cat']
  disp (i);
end
```

and give the same result.

Is there an option in Matlab to do this?

**ADDITION:**

I need the words as strings later on to use and not just to display (the `disp` was just as an example). I've tried to use cell arrays in my real program:

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

global fp_a
global TEST_TYPE
global SHADE_METHODE

for fp_a=11:24
for shade={'full','fast'}
    SHADE_METHODE=shade(1);
    for test={'bunny','city'}
        TEST_MODE=test(1);
        fprintf ('fp_a:%d | test: %s | shade: %s',fp_a,TEST_TYPE,SHADE_METHODE);
        ray_tracing;
    end
end
end
```

It doesn't work as the values stay as cells and not strings I get the error message:

> ??? Error using ==> fprintf Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

*-I don't really need the `fprintf` I just use it to check that the values are correct.

**-`ray_tracing` is my code that uses the values of the strings

Comment: The problem in the addition is just syntax. You need to use the curly braces - `test{1}` - to extract the char array from the cell, not normal parentheses - `test(1)` - which just select the first cell in the array, effectively doing nothing here. Check Oli's example code again; note he's using the curly braces in `i{1}`. (Also, don't use globals if you can avoid it.)

Comment: You should use `SHADE_METHODE=shade{1};` instead of `SHADE_METHODE=shade(1);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a foreach in MATLAB? If so, how does it behave if the underlying data changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408080/is-there-a-foreach-in-matlab-if-so-how-does-it-behave-if-the-underlying-data-c)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Or you can do:

```
for i={'cow','dog','cat'}
   disp(i{1})
end
```

Result:

```
cow
dog
cat
```

Comment: Nice. If only every really nice thing about writing in Matlab weren't offset by something truly horrible.

Answer (score 6):

Your problems are probably caused by the way MATLAB handles strings. MATLAB strings are just arrays of characters. When you call `['cow','dog','cat']`, you are forming `'cowdogcat'` because `[]` concatenates arrays without any nesting. If you want nesting behaviour you can use cell arrays which are built using `{}`. `for` iterates over the columns of its right hand side. This means you can use the idiom you mentioned above; Oli provided a solution already. This idiom is also a good way to showcase the difference between normal and cell arrays.

```
%Cell array providing the correct solution
for word = {'cow','dog','cat'}
    disp(word{1}) %word is bound to a 1x1 cell array. This extracts its contents.
end

cow
dog
cat


%Normal array providing weirdness
for word = ['cow','dog','cat'] %Same as word = 'cowdogcat'
    disp(word) %No need to extract content
end

c
o
w
d
o
g
c
a
t
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure! Use cell arrays for keeping strings (in normal arrays, strings are considered by character, which could work if all strings have the same length, but will bork otherwise).

```
opts={'cow','dog','cat'}
for i=1:length(opts)
    disp(opts{i})
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string arrays which where introduced in R2017a I believe. Note the double-quotes:

```
for i = ["cow", "dog", "cat"]
  disp(i);
end
```