# For loop running over different variables

Tags: matlab

Good day,

I would like to do the following in Matlab:

```
var1 = 10;
var2 = 15;
var3 = 20;

j = 1;

for i = [var1,var2,var3]
    a(j) = i + 10;
    j = j + 1;
end
clear j;
```

With result:

```
a(1) = var1 + 10 = 20
a(2) = var1 + 10 = 25 
a(3) = var1 + 10 = 30
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what's wrong with `a = [var1, var2, var3] + 10`? It accomplishes the same.

Comment: Because my real situation is much more complex than this example.

Comment: I can't answer the question without knowing the real situation. What is your question?

Comment: I simply want a variables name within a loop to change every time the loop runs.

Comment: it is still not clear, can you provide a better illustrative example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Engaging heavy use of crystal ball.  It appears that you'd like to dynamically generate the names var1, var2, etc.  Don't.  There is just about never an advantage to naming variables this way.  Use cell arrays instead:

```
var{1} = 10;
var{2} = 15;
var{3} = 20;
```

so that you can just use:

```
for i = 1:length(var)
    a(j) = var{i} + 10;
...
```

Note the curly brace.

If your variables are all the same size, it's even better to use array slices.  `var(:, i)` or `var(:,:,:,i)`, for example

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question with a successful answer: [foreach loop with strings in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826040/foreach-loop-in-matlab)

maybe use the cell array syntax with {}:

```
for i = {var1,var2,var3}
a(j) = i + 10;
j = j + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Both @FloHin and @Peter have mentioned using cells, which is a great method to help you when you have a limited number of non-scalar variables. In case you are dealing with unknown number of such variables that follow a certain format, you can use `eval` function to get the value of the current variable on-demand:

```
var1 = 10;
var2 = 15;
var3 = 20;
var4 = 30;
# ...
# more variables following the varN = x pattern

all_variables = who('var*');
num = numel(all_variables);
a = zeros(num, 1);
for i = 1:num
    a(i) = eval(all_variables{i}) + 10;
end
```