# FOR loop over column vector vs row vector

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I was just writing a "kinda-foreach" loop in Matlab and encountered this strange behavior:

I have the matrix A:

```
A = [
 3
 9
 5
 0];
```

And I want to use a `foreach` loop (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408080/is-there-a-foreach-in-matlab-if-so-how-does-it-behave-if-the-underlying-data-c)) on the A.

If I write this:

```
for i = A
     disp('for')
     i    
end
```

The result will be:

```
for

i =

     3
     9
     5
     0
```

But when I use the transpose, the result will change:

```
for i = A'
     disp('for')
     i    
end
```

Result:

```
for

i =

     3

for

i =

     9

for

i =

     5

for

i =

     0
```

Which is the result I want.

Can anybody explain what's going on here? What's the difference between these two cases?

Answer (score 6):

when you type

```
A = [
3
9
5
0];
```

you create a column vector. Because Matlab iterates over columns you get one answer (the first column). By transposing it you get a row vector with 4 columns and therefore 4 answers each with one column.

Answer (score 5):

In Matlab, the `for` loop iterates over columns. http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/for.html