# Number of iterations in a loop

Tags: matlab

Why does the following code

```
for a=1:5:100
    a = a+ 1;
end
```

iterate 20 times?

`a` goes up by 5 every iteration, but also goes up by 1 in the actual loop. 99/6 = 16.5 or 17 iterations, so why does it do 20?

Thanks for any help understanding how the for loop function works.

Comment: why you are dividing it by 6 instead of 5 because increment is of 5 not of 6.

Comment: It's bad practice to change the index of a loop within the loop itself.

Comment: Himanshu: Because a goes up by 1 in the actual loop as well.

Comment: am304: It may be, the question I'm getting this from asks specifically how many times the code iterates. I'm not using it for anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Matlab, whatever you do to the loop index variable (`a`) inside a `for` loop is thrown away, and `a` gets reset at the beginning of the next pass. So the `a = a + 1` inside the loop has no effect. See [Is there a foreach in MATLAB? If so, how does it behave if the underlying data changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408080/is-there-a-foreach-in-matlab-if-so-how-does-it-behave-if-the-underlying-data-c).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike languages like C or C++, changing the loop index in MATLAB is not persistent across loop iterations.

In other words, if you increment `a`, it will remain incremented for the rest of that loop. However, upon reaching the top of the loop, MATLAB does not add 5 to `a`. Instead, it selects the next value of `a` from the list of values you provided. This effectively "overwrites" the change that you made to the loop index inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The way to view a `for` loop in MATLAB like this one,

```
for a=1:5:100
```

Is to provide an array directly,

```
ai = [1:5:100];
for a = ai
```

The loop will iterate over the values in `ai`. Period. It doesn't matter what you do to `a` in the loop. At the beginning of each iteration, the value of `a` gets set according to the array given to the `for` statement.